# Wordpress theme doesn't output more than one post per tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We created a Wordpress theme based off of the Blankslate theme.  In `tag.php` I see this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="blog-content">
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Tag Archives:', 'blankslate' ) ?> <span><?php single_tag_title() ?></span></h1>
    <?php rewind_posts(); 
    get_template_part( 'nav', 'above' );

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'entry' );
    }

    get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' ); ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

We have multiple posts tagged "document management" for example, but when we browse to the tag, we only ever see the latest post.  What can I change to see all the posts for a given tag?

Comment: I love how even just **looking** at wordpress code makes me feel like I need to go have a bath...

Comment: Why do you use so many opening and closing PHP tags?

Comment: I'll edit here in a moment.  This is how the template came.

Comment: There's not enough information in what you've posted to solve your problem, but only guess at it. Assuming the posts exist and are properly tagged, I'd venture to cast suspicion on the multiple templates included by **tag.php** and the **templates included by the templates** which I've seen in this theme. @.@

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the loop within wordpress, set some arguments like this and then pass the arguments through the `WP_QUERY`

E.G

This will get the latest posts

```
$args = array(
post_type => 'post',
posts_per_page => '20',
tax_query => array(
             array( 
             'taxonomy' => 'category',
             'terms => 'your custom slug here'
             'field' => 'slug'
),
),
);

$query = wp_query($args)
```

then pass $query to the posts like so

```
while($query->have_posts() : $query->the_posts();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try to remove this script  ?

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
```

under tag `<div id="blog-content">`

and this one

```
rewind_posts();
```

it seems you don't need that script. and i think that's the problem.